# Question about Charles' law:

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, ideal-gas, volume

Charles's law says that the volume of a given mass of a gas is directly proportional to its absolute temperature. This means if we increase one, the other one is automatically increased.

So the question that my mind is not accepting is: if we increase volume, than temperature will also increased, but in my observations, volume increased the temperature decreased? How is that possible?

Comment: Need to add .... at constant pressure.

Answer (score 3):

Charle's Law, I believe, says that if you increase volume while maintaining a constant pressure, that the temperature will increase.   Key to that relation is that a constant pressure is maintained.

A more general law than charles law is the ideal gas equation.  $PV=nk T$  If you take $P$ to be constant in the ideal gas equation you get $V\propto T$ which is when Charles law is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is that you would need some mechanical method to achieve by  'injecting' kinetic energy into that volume. I suppose you could "pump" a piston back and forth until the temperature were increased by adiabatic compression cycles. Or you could put a paddle on an axle and spin it until the temperature reached a higher level of your choosing. The causal direction is *usually* the other way round, you alter the temperature to effect a change in volume (at constant pressure.